# Probability of selecting x black marbles in a row

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If i have a jar with an infinite amount of marbles, whites and black ones.

Each time i pick a marble there is 0.46 probability that it is white, and 0.54 probability that it is black.

What is the probability that i at some point picked 7 black marbles in a row after 400 trials. And can this be generalized to probability of at some point having picked x black marbles in a row after n trials?

What kind of probabilistic model can be used for this kind of task?
Thanks alot

Comment: Title says white, question says black. Presumably picking $8$ black marbles in a row counts as $7$ having been achieves

Comment: When you write "at some point" then the answer is obvious:  the probability is 100%.  Just keep picking sequences of length 400 and at *some* point you're guaranteed (in probability) to select 7 black marbles in a row.